# Implemented a Local PIN lock: Recovery Best Practice?

Tags: security, windows-phone-8, passwords

I decided to implement a stored PIN setup in my app. It stores the hashed pin and a salt (regenerated every PIN change). This is all local and I was initially trying to avoid having the user need to be online. Is there a best practice for having them recover access since it's all offline?

In Detail:
What I'm wondering is, since I've done it this way, there is no way for the user to access the app if they truly have forgotten their four digit PIN.

I was hoping to find reassurance if this is an acceptable route to go forward on - There are localized warnings and explanations before the PIN is set, and it's not set by default. The hash and salt are stored locally. I also warn the user to backup the local database before enabling the PIN. Are these precautions enough for "fair warning"? Or should I opt for a net service account or my own service (all of which I admit I was trying to avoid online).

Comment: If the PIN is really only hashed once, and there are only 10,000 possibilities, then the user can pull out even the poorest performing hashing software and brute-force the entire keyspace in virtually no time.  With only a 4 digit PIN, there's virtually nothing you can do to prevent this - if you spend 3.6 seconds hashing the password with SCrypt/BCrypt/PBKDF2, then even the same device could brute-force the entire keyspace in 10 hours.  If you spend only 0.01 seconds hashing the password, then exhaustively searching the entire keyspace would take less than 2 minutes.

Comment: Thanks for the input, I'll keep that in mind. But separately, I was asking if there was a best practice for the user to recover his/her PIN or app access since I want to keep this offline. I've edited my post to be a little clearer.

Comment: Provide the brute force app to the users yourself as a "recover lost PIN" app :) - otherwise they'll have to find one somewhere else, and may get malware.